# Migrando do WebForms para o MVC, qual a melhor maneira de armazenar e manipular os dados de um usuário logado?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Durante anos trabalhei com sistemas c# em **WebForms**, porém, por necessidade migrei meu objetivo de desenvolvimento para aplicações mobile com *Xamarin* e padrões *MVVM*.

Agora em paralelo estou desenvolvendo novamente sistemas WEB porém, em padrões MVC. Mas uma uma dúvida vem me perseguindo...

Em WebForms, sempre utilizei **Session** para tratar o usuário logado pela **MasterPage¹**.
Agora em MVC, onde **Filters** e **Roles** são itens básicos de um bom projeto, qual a melhor forma de armazenar os dados do usuário logado? Pois preciso carregar os dados do usuário logado na View e também preciso dos dados para salvar registros no banco e etc.

Atualmente venho utilizando uma filter para verificar o estado da sessão, e ainda estou felizmente/infelizmente utilizando **Session** para salvar² seus dados e manipula-los, porém, como todos sabem as Session's dependendo do tanto de usuários logado, acaba consumindo muitos recursos do servidor.

Como fazer? Mantenho as Session's? Utilizo Cookie? TempData? ViewBag? ou outro...

¹ Em uma aplicação WebForms eu havia uma classe por ex: UsuarioLogado, que continha os dados de UsuarioId, Nome, Email, Foto etc.

Eu realizava as verificações na PageLoad da MasterPage simplesmente utilizando:

```
if(UsuarioLogado.UsuarioId < 1)
   Response.Redirect("~/Login");
```

² Nas aplicações atuais em MVC, eu também utilizo uma classe para salver os dados do usuário: 
Abaixo, utilizo uma classe para passar os dados que consultei no banco para salvar na Session:

```
private void SessionAdd(Usuario dados)
{
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("UsuarioId", dados.UsuarioId);
}
```

Utilizo também uma Filter `IAuthorizationFilter` que faz o seguinte:

```
public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            if (filterContext.ActionDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof(AllowAnonymousAttribute), true)
                || filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof(AllowAnonymousAttribute), true))
            {
            return;
        }

        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Session != null && filterContext.HttpContext.Session["UsuarioId"] == null)
        {
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("~/Login/Acesso");
        }
    }
```

Quando eu preciso dos dados para exibir na View, simplesmente faço `@Session["Nome"]`.
Minhas aplicações vem funcionando, porém, acredito que a maneira com a qual faço a manipulação funciona bem somente para poucos usuários logados, mas não é a melhor maneira para muitos usuários.

Comment: Será que poderia adicionar mais algumas informações para nos ajudar?
 Algo como quais dados do usuário você gostaria de armazenar? Nome e ID? Está utilizando Identity? Poderia [edit] e adicionar como está fazendo a autenticação?

Comment: Você já tem algo pronto em Asp.NET MVC? Aproveitando, qual versão está utilizando?

Comment: Sim, as aplicações onde eu trabalho já estou migrando para MVC, cerca de 4 aplicações já foram totalmente migradas. Quanto a versão, estou utilizando a 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Respondendo de forma simples baseado na experiência que tive.

Fiz uma classe/filter que cuida dos usuários logados, além de validar se ele pode ou não acessar tal classe, isto baseado em "roles" que fiz de uma forma genérica.

Também salvei os dados em uma classe, Id, Nome e Perfil para que eu possa comparar na minha Filter.

```
public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
    //Se não tiver mais session, ou não logado, redireciona para o login
    if(Logado.UsuarioId < 1)
        return filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("~/Login/Acesso");

    //Pega qual controller e action ele quer acessar
    var actionName = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName;
    var controllerName = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName;

    if(!isEnable(actionName, controllerName))
        return filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("~/Error/Permitido");
}

//Lógica para verificar se permite ou não o usuário
private bool isEnable (string action, string controller){
    return true;
}
```

E ai eu só preciso alterar a lógica da função isEnable, colocando o que deve ser checado para informar se ele pode ou não acessar.

Comment: em que momento e aonde é chamado essa classe OnAuthorization ? @Thiago Araújo